# The correct way of using chmod in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the file permission of a specific php file on the webserver through php. 
The first thing I did was check [php.net](http://php.net).

I embedded this code:

```
<?php @chmod("http://www.example.com/includes/config.php", 0777); ?>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can only `chmod` files on your filesystem, not a URL.  You need to do `chmod('/path/on/your/server/config.php', 0777);`.

Comment: Lordie! If that were possible, the Web would be absolute mayhem (*more than it is now*). Plus, "food for thought". Don't post actual URL's

Comment: @Fred hahaha yes true that

Answer (score 3):

You're providing a URL when you should be using a path.

E.g.

```
<?php @chmod("/path/to/webroot/includes/config.php", 0777); ?>
```

Make sure you update this with the correct path.

Comment: I get this error "Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /www/htdocs/nether/http/mailtogopro/includes/config.php on line 2"

Comment: Try using a relative path then. I.e: `("../includes/config.php", 0777)` modify `../` according to the file's location. @Julian

Comment: Try removing the @ symbol. @Julian

Comment: Don't remove the @. This has nothing to do with the error. Your setup is preventing your code from modifying file permissions. You'll need to change the server owner / group permissions to allow this.

Comment: How do I do that by script?

Comment: You can't. You need to login by SSH and make the change.